# How to return a String Builder Object at once as an rdd ? Or Convert a String Builder object to an rdd?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, stringbuilder, rdd

In the below code I am trying read a text file as an rdd and I am calling the map method because I want to transpose each line and append it to the String Builder object. But I want to return the String Builder object after I have finished with each line . But here I am returning it at each line . So when I do a exposuresRdd.saveAsTextFile().

I am getting the output as (repeats) 
a
b

a
b
c

a
b
c
d

where as I want it to be 
a
b
c
d
e
f

It should not repeat

```
JavaRDD<String> exposuresRdd = ctx.textFile(fname);

JavaRDD<String> transformedrdd= exposuresRdd.flatMap(new Function<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String call(String line) throws Exception {
sb.append(Something);
return sb.toString();

});
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question here - if you want to return the string at the end of each line, then the output will be a repeat of previous lines + the new line. Also surely you would be saving transformedRdd and not exposuresRdd.saveAsTextFile()?

Comment: Please  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear what you want and your code is incomplete. It looks like you make exactly the same type of mistake as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32798554/1560062)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all at the end I would save transformedRdd.saveAstextFile() and not exposuresRdd as   Gillespie says.

I was able to resolve the issue of the data repeating by using a new String Builder object when ever returning the string .

As using the same String Builder object would already contain the previous lines appended to it , I was getting the repeated data in my final output.

```
JavaRDD<String> exposuresRdd = ctx.textFile(fname);

StringBuilder sb = null;
JavaRDD<String> transformedrdd= exposuresRdd.flatMap(new Function<String,String>() {

    @Override
    public String call(String line) throws Exception {
sb = new StringBuilder(); 
sb.append(Something);
return sb.toString();

 });
}
```

This will make sure that every time you return the StringBuilder object it will have only the data appended to it at that particular call.
The output now would be 
  - > a b c d e f
If we use the same StringBuilder object for all the calls , the output would have been -> a
ab
abc abcd abcde abcdef
(because of the data appended to the StringBuilder object in the previous calls.)